# If $0 < a < b,$ there exists an $x_{0}$ such that for $x \geq x_0$ there is at least one prime between $ax$ and $bx.$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

My approach: I first showed that for $0 < a < b,~\pi(ax) < \pi(bx)$ if $x \geq x_{0}.$ Now, since $\pi$ is an integer valued function, $\pi(bx) - \pi(ax) \geq 1$ for all $x \geq x_0.$ i.e. the difference between the number of primes not exceeding $bx$ and the number of primes not exceeding $ax$ is an integer $\geq 1.$

How to complete the proof ? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does follow from the prime number theorem:
$$
\pi(x)\sim\frac{x}{\log x}
$$

Indeed
$$
\pi(ax)\sim\frac{ax}{\log ax},
\quad
\pi(bx)\sim\frac{bx}{\log bx}
$$
imply
$$
\frac{\pi(bx)}{\pi(ax)} \sim \frac{bx}{ax}\frac{\log ax}{\log bx}
\sim \frac{b}{a} > 1
$$
This implies that for $x \ge x_0$, we have $\pi(bx) > \pi(ax)$. Since they are both integers, we have $\pi(bx) \ge \pi(ax)+1$.

Comment: @Eureka, $\pi(bx) \ge \pi(ax)+1$ iff $\pi(bx) - \pi(ax) \ge 1$.